# Suggestions for data entry form in android

Tags: android

I am working on app which have data entry form which have

1. Some fields with 3 drop down associated to it.
2. More then 25 input fields (input box, radio button, drop downs etc)
3. All input fields are grouped into 3 categories

My question are:

1. How to display field with 3 drop downs associated with it ? Because of a small screen size it cannot be displayed horizontally.
2. What is the best way to represent 25+ fields ? I tried scroll view and tabs but don't find it so pleasing.
   For example if you consider date then it may have three drop downs for date , month and year. (Its just example I have fields different than date)
3. What is the good way to have fields in a category together with appealing UI.

**PS:** My app is related to Hospital so it has to be pleasant .Which also means I cannot use glossy background or image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check [this site](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/) for general Android UI design ideas. Here are some for your particular cases:

- re-design your UI to only show what is needed. It's unlikely that all 25 fields are used all of the time. Consider separate screens for different use cases, and/or some sort of wizard-like UI (fill in the basics, press next, fill in details, etc.)
- if you really need to display all of this, consider using a tablet, not a phone to run the app (assuming this is to be used in the field, and you have some control over devices).
- instead of tabs, you might want to try something like [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html). It doesn't take as much space as tabs, and the number of views is practically unlimited.

Comment: Thanks for the link.The app is mainly designed for mobile devices so I have to find some workarund.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe like this...

You can use the library [QuickAction](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) which allows to create some kind of context menu.

To keep a simple screen view, you can only display the current values. Several on the same lines for the same category.
Then, if the user click on a value or category, you trigger a QuickAction with the actions available for the category or values: Edit, clear, ...
For each action, you can also show a dialog to update/fill the field which has triggered the action...